# How to update a Toast from an async task on onProgressUpdate without FREEZING the view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to update a toast on downloading files which are done really quickly (a few ms)... So as I have to update the view, and so the toast, on the main thread, it freezes the view.

onProgressUpdate I call

```
            if(toast != null)
                toast.cancel();

            toast = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            toast.show();
```

### Solution

```
 if(toast != null)
        {
            toast.setText(message);

            if(!toast.getView().isShown())
                toast.show();
        }
        else
        {
            toast = Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
```

Comment: do you call  your toast inside the asynctask?

Comment: No, from outside... I was unable to "update" I mean cancel the old toast and replace it by the new one. It was working without no lag but I was enable to call cancel on it by storing a ref into my async task... Tx for your response !

Comment: So just remove your toast.cancel() and do an If / else directly

Comment: One cannot update a toast. One can display a toast in onProgressUpdate and it will not slow down download. It is unclear what you mean with it freezes the view.

Comment: `No, from outside..` ??? In onProgressUpdate you suggested. What do you mean exactly? Are you caling onProgressUpdate yourself? Dont do that to begin with. It is called automatically when you use publishProgress. Keep your hands off it.

Comment: I don't call onProgressUpdate of course but publishProgress on doInBackground. But I found the solution. Txs for your reponses guys

See edited question